# Python Vectorize Code

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have this function that I call in a for loop. It is a contact tracing function for a hospital project. Basically, it calculates the distance between the x and y coordinates of two sets of coordinates, patients in this case. The function is as such:

```
def inContact(patientID, patientLng, patientLat, dev, index, _data, mapScale, distance):
    contact = []
    contactX = _data.loc[dev, 'Beacon Longtitude'].tolist()
    contactY = _data.loc[dev, 'Beacon Latitude'].tolist()
    latVect = math.fabs(float(patientLng[index]) - float(contactX[index])) * int(mapScale)
    lngVect = math.fabs(float(patientLat[index]) - float(contactY[index])) * int(mapScale)
    if latVect < distance and lngVect < distance:
        contact.append(contactX[index])
        contact.append(contactY[index])
        return True, contact
    return False, contact
```

While, the `patientLng` and `patientLat` is the same for every iteration, the `dev` and `index` changes. I am really confused as to how I may vectorize this code.

So far, I think I do not need to send in the `dev` and `index` number any more.

1. So do I make the `contactX` and `contactY` lists numpy arrays? and then how do I actually check the results one by one later?
2. Will `latVect` and `lngVect` immediately become numpy arrays too?

Some suggestions would be highly appreciated!

P.S. The `_data` attribute is a pandas dataframe object.

Edit: I have shifted this part of the code outside of the function

```
if latVect < distance and lngVect < distance:
    contact.append(contactX[index])
    contact.append(contactY[index])
    return True, contact
return False, contact
```

The function now looks like this:

```
contactX = np.array(_data.loc[dev, 'Beacon Longtitude'].tolist())
contactY = np.array(_data.loc[dev, 'Beacon Latitude'].tolist())
patientX = np.array(patientLng)
patientY = np.array(patientLat)
latVect = np.abs(float(patientX) - float(contactX)) * int(mapScale)
lngVect = np.abs(float(patientY) - float(contactY)) * int(mapScale)
return latVect, lngVect
```

However, now I get the error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars to the line

```
latVect = np.abs(float(patientX) - float(contactX)) * int(mapScale)
```

Anyone knows why? I read online that numpy vectorization can't accept math functions so I changed it to np.abs but I still get the error.

Comment: Use `patientX.astype(float)` instead of `float(patientX)`. And you can try `_data.loc[dev, 'Beacon Longtitude'].values` which makes your code shorter.

Comment: @kitman0804 Thank you so much! That got rid of the error.